# DATEIME_DIFF throwing error when using safe divide

Tags: google-bigquery

I've created a query that I'm hoping to use to fill a table with *daily budgets* at the end of every day. To do this, I just need some simple maths:
monthly budget / number of days left in the month.

Then, at the end of the month, I can SUM all of the rows to calculate an accurate budget.

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT *,
ROUND(SAFE_DIVIDE(budget, DATETIME_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE()), DAY)),2) AS daily_budget
FROM `mm-demo-project.marketing_hub.budget_manager`
```

When executing the query, my results present as negative numbers, which according to the [documentation for this function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#datetime_diff), is likely caused by the result overflowing the result type.

View the [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jQbs.png) of the query.

I've made a fools guess at rounding the calculation. Needless to say that it did not work at all.

How can I stop my query from returning negative number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below

```
SELECT *,
ROUND(SAFE_DIVIDE(budget, DATETIME_DIFF(LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE()), CURRENT_DATE(), DAY)),2) AS daily_budget
FROM `mm-demo-project.marketing_hub.budget_manager`
```